# Adding a suffix to the variable in a mixin?

Tags: css, sass

I have a mixin:

```
@mixin transition($duration) {
  -webkit-transition: all $durations ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all $durations ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all $durations ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all $durations ease-in-out;
          transition: all $durations ease-in-out;
}
```

but in its current state it's broken because it's clearly going to look for a variable named `$durations` instead of `$duration` and then suffixing an `s` for seconds. Is there a way to pull this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation:

```
@mixin transition($duration) {
  -webkit-transition: all #{$duration}s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all #{$duration}s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all #{$duration}s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all #{$duration}s ease-in-out;
          transition: all #{$duration}s ease-in-out;
}

.foo {
  @include transition(1);
}
```